# What does one do with a recipe?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a verb that means following the instructions written in a recipe.

Comment: Implement it :)))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You **follow** the recipe, as you said in your question.  There is no other verb that I'm aware of.

Comment: I agree; *follow* is the most natural verb. However, as a matter of completeness, I'd also mention that you can [*abide by*](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=pp#hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22abide+by+the+recipe%22) or [*stick to*](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=pp#hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22stick+to+the+recipe%22) a recipe (or, if you are particularly adventurous, you can [*deviate from*](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=pp#hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22deviate+from+the+recipe%22) a recipe).

Comment: You could also (just about) ["**carry out** the recipe"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22carry+out+the+recipe%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (or maybe even *work though* it), but I agree *follow* is by far the most common. With even *stick to* a pretty distant second.

Comment: @J.R. & FumbleFingers - Yes, quite true.   I was actually just trying to say that there's no single verb for "Follow a Recipe" as a unified thought.  It's always "(something) the recipe."